# Collect2 error while installing yay for Arch Linux

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux

I have no idea why that happening. Google didn't help me.

> **OS:** Arch Linux (64-bit)
>   **Kernel:** 4.18.5-arch1-1-ARCH

I tried to install yay for my Arch Linux, but faced with an error.

Here is the log:

```
==> Making package: yay 9.1.0-1 (Mon 18 Feb 2019 08:01:59 PM MSK)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found yay-9.1.0.tar.gz
==> Validating source files with sha1sums...
    yay-9.1.0.tar.gz ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting yay-9.1.0.tar.gz with bsdtar
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
go build -v -ldflags '-s -w -X main.version=9.1.0' -o yay -mod=vendor
# github.com/Jguer/yay/v9
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-743391074/000012.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-743391074/000012.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-743391074/000012.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-743391074/000012.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/tmp/go-link-743391074/000012.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [Makefile:51: build] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You might get better answers from the Penguins at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you perhaps running out of space in /tmp?

Comment: @grawity Hmm, I have free 3.8 GiB out of 3.8 GiB in /tmp, I think that's not the reason.

Comment: @HackSlash Do I need to move/copy my question?

Comment: You can copy. It's okay to post the question in multiple places but I would generally only post it in the most specific place that you can.

Comment: @HackSlash Thanks for help, I'll keep it in mind for future.